# Deserializing from BsonDocument to string and serializing back to BsonDocument

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, serialization, bson

I have a requirement where I need a property that is actually a JSON value from a MongoDB collection that needs to be deserialized into a string. This conversion is throwing a *"Cannot deserialize a 'String' from a BsonType 'Document'"* exception.

I tried implementing a JSON custom converter, but as the value is being treated as a BsonDocument, it is not helping and I am getting the same exception. I also need it in the original format as I need to cast it back into a BsonDocument down the line. I guess I would need a custom Bson serializer/deserializer.

Incoming sample document from MongoDB collection:

```
{
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "dob": {
        "month": "Sep",
        "day": 09,
        "year": 1987
    }
}
```

Type it is expecting for deserialization:

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Dob dob { get; set; }

    public class Dob
    {
        public string month { get; set; }
        public int day { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Type I want it to deserialize into:

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize, you have a public-facing `string` property on your model that contains JSON which you would like to internally serialize to MongoDB by deserializing the JSON string to some intermediate [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), then serializing the DTO itself to Mongo.

Here are a couple of approaches to solving your problem.

**Firstly**, you could introduce a private DTO-valued property `Dob SerializedDOB { get; set; }` into your data model, mark that property with [`[BsonElement("dob")]`](https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_Attributes_BsonElementAttribute.htm) to force it to be serialized, then modify `dob` to be a non-serialized surrogate property that serializes from and to the underlying `SerializedDOB` within its getter and setter.  The following code shows this approach:

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnore]
    public string dob
    {
        get => BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson(SerializedDOB);
        set => SerializedDOB = MyBsonExtensionMethods.FromJson<Dob>(value);
    }

    [BsonElement("dob")]
    Dob SerializedDOB { get; set; }

    class Dob // The DTO
    {
        public string month { get; set; }
        public int day { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that, by making the JSON string a surrogate, the setter automatically ensures that it is well-formed.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T4Hmav).

**Secondly**, you could create a custom [`SerializerBase<string>`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_Serializers_SerializerBase_1.htm) for `dob` that maps the string value to and from the DTO `Dob` during (de)serialization.  The following code shows this approach:

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    [BsonSerializer(typeof(JsonStringAsObjectSerializer<Dob>))]
    public string dob { get; set; }

    class Dob // The DTO
    {
        public string month { get; set; }
        public int day { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
    }
}

public class JsonStringAsObjectSerializer<TObject> : SerializerBase<string> where TObject : class
{
    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            var bsonWriter = context.Writer;
            bsonWriter.WriteNull();
        }
        else
        {
            var obj = MyBsonExtensionMethods.FromJson<TObject>(value);
            var serializer = BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(typeof(TObject));
            serializer.Serialize(context, obj);
        }           
    }

    public override string Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var bsonReader = context.Reader;
        var serializer = BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(typeof(TObject));
        var obj = (TObject)serializer.Deserialize(context);
        return (obj == null ? null : BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson(obj));
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that `JsonStringAsObjectSerializer<TObject>` can be reused whenever this requirement arises.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yw9NWc).

The following extension method is used with both solutions to deserialize the JSON string to a specified type because, confusingly, [`BsonExtensionMethods`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_BsonExtensionMethods.htm) has a [`ToJson()`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_BsonExtensionMethods_ToJson.htm) method but no `FromJson()` method:

```
public static partial class MyBsonExtensionMethods
{
    // Not sure why but BsonExtensionMethods.cs seems to lack methods for deserializing from JSON, so I added some here.
    // See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/BsonExtensionMethods.cs 

    public static TNominalType FromJson<TNominalType>(
        string json,
        JsonReaderSettings readerSettings = null,
        IBsonSerializer<TNominalType> serializer = null,
        Action<BsonDeserializationContext.Builder> configurator = null)
    {
        return (TNominalType)FromJson(json, typeof(TNominalType), readerSettings, serializer, configurator);
    }

    public static object FromJson(
        string json,
        Type nominalType,
        JsonReaderSettings readerSettings = null,
        IBsonSerializer serializer = null,
        Action<BsonDeserializationContext.Builder> configurator = null)
    {
        if (nominalType == null || json == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        serializer = serializer ?? BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(nominalType);
        if (serializer.ValueType != nominalType)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("serializer.ValueType {0} != nominalType {1}.", serializer.GetType().FullName, nominalType.FullName), "serializer");

        using (var textReader = new StringReader(json)) 
        using (var reader = new JsonReader(textReader, readerSettings ?? JsonReaderSettings.Defaults))
        {
            var context = BsonDeserializationContext.CreateRoot(reader, configurator);
            return serializer.Deserialize(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any news about the solution ?